# iOS How to fetch data for each user parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How can I fetch data for user which I want.
For this I want use text field where I write username, and button which will load all information about user.
Now my code load all user from data base:

```
 let query = PFUser.query()
    query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (object, error) in
        for objects in object! {
            let user = objects["username"] as! String
            print(user)

        }

    })
```

> How I can make it for user which I want?

Answer (score 2):

You *could* filter the users locally like this:

```
query?.findObjectsInBackground {(objects, error) in
    let users = objects as? [PFUser]
    for object in (users!.filter { $0.username == something }) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But that's a pretty bad idea because your list of users might be huge and this is wildly inefficient. If you're using `PFQuery`, you might want to add a constraint:

```
let query = PFUser.query()
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: something)
```

Now, when you call `findObjectsInBackground`, you'll only get relevant results.

Answer (score 1):

**You are getting user list in `object` at:**

```
query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (object, error) in
```

> Put a `where` clause in `for` loop, to get a single user by matching your required username as:

```
    for objects in object! where (objects["username"] as! String) == "Your_Text_Field.text" {
        print(objects)

        let userName = objects["username"] as! String
        print(userName)
    }
```

> If you don't want to match exact name rather you want to get a list of user by searching with entered text, then you can apply filter:

```
    query?.findObjectsInBackground {(object, error) in
        if let users = object as? [PFUser] {
            let filteredUsers = users.filter { $0.username.contains("Your_Text_Field.text") }
            print(filteredUsers)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any!' and 'String'

Comment: @Andrew, Just cast the `objects["username"]` to `String`. I have updated my answer.